# How to debug mappings of structs in truffle tests

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

This is my test file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Salaries.sol";

contract TestSalaries {

    function testEmployeeInsertion() public {
        Salaries salaries = Salaries(DeployedAddresses.Salaries());
        address addr = address(0);
        salaries.addEmployee(address(0), "Alicia Drake", "Lead Engineer");
        Assert.equal(salaries.employees(addr).name, "Alicia Drake");
    }
}
```

And the definitions in `Salaries.sol`:

```
struct Employee {
    string name;
    string role;
}
mapping (address => Employee) public employees;
```

How can I write tests for verifying the employee's name and role? Currently, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is tuple(string memory,string memory))
        Assert.equal(salaries.employees(addr)[0], "Alicia Drake");
```

Similarly, is there a way to log the variables in the console while running the tests?

Using `truffle 4.1.14`.

Comment: One workaround when using solidity is to emit events as messages, for example event consolelog (string test) or event consolelog (string name), but this approach is somewhat inflexible, I believe that javascript tests are more flexible in logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to debug `truffle` tests it is much more convenient to write tests in `javascript`

In your case you need to use `[]` instead of `()`

```
salaries.employees[addr].name
```

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#mappings

Here are all possible signatures for `equal`:

```
function equal(string a, string b, string message) public returns (bool result)
function equal(bytes32 a, bytes32 b, string message) public returns (bool result)
function equal(address a, address b, string message) public returns (bool result)
function equal(bool a, bool b, string message) public returns (bool result)
function equal(uint a, uint b, string message) public returns (bool result)
function equal(int a, int b, string message) public returns (bool result)
function equal(uint[] arrA, uint[] arrB, string message) public returns (bool result)
function equal(int[] arrA, int[] arrB, string message) public returns (bool result)
function equal(address[] arrA, address[] arrB, string message) public returns (bool result)
function equal(bytes32[] arrA, bytes32[] arrB, string message) public returns (bool result)
```

Answer (score -1):

expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is tuple(string memory,string memory))
        Assert.equal(salaries.employees(addr)[0], "Alicia Drake");